# Dynamic linking on macOS : is ImageIO.framework broken?

Tags: dynamic-linking, libjpeg, dyld, macos-big-sur

I have build the gmsh software on macOS BigSur 11.0.1. When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
Abort trap: 6
```

Surprisingly, checking with `otool -L` reveals that /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO does not exist

```
$otool -L /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/objdump: error: '/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO': No such file or directory
```

while libjpeg.9.dylib is really in /usr/local/lib.

Also, the directory /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Ressources exists but does not contain any library files.

I have tried to reinstall libjpeg with brew but it does not change anything.

I'm a stuck on this problem for days.
Has anyone a suggestion?

Comment: (Does `otool` check "well known" suffixes? What does `ls -ld /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO*` yield?)

Comment: `ls -ld /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO*` yields :
ls: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO*: No such file or directory.

      However directory /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources exists.